# Validate Unique to only have one Property from a certain PropertyCategory

Tags: python, django

```
class PropertyCategory(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Property Category')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Property Categories')



class Property(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey(PropertyCategory)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Properties'



class Variant(models.Model):

    properties = models.ManyToManyField(Property)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        product = Product.objects.get(variants__id=self.id)

        return '%s (%s)' % (product.name, ', '.join([c.name for c in self.properties.all()]))
```

How can I validate my Variant on Creation/Update that it can only have *one* `Property` from the same `PropertyCategory`.

Let's say I have this product; `Lace-trim Cheeky Panty (Pink, XS)`, where the properties between the parentheses are the `Properties` from `PropertyCategory` `Color` and `Size`. I want to restrict the `Variant` to only be able to have one of each `PropertyCategory`, so stuff like this won't happen;

`Lace-trim Cheeky Panty (Pink, XS, Blue, M)`

Besides that I am wondering maybe to set a special value on the `PropertyCategory` if it ***is*** allowed to have multiple. Let's say Washing Instructions ***can*** occur more than once. How would I catch that difference?

```
class PropertyCategory(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    multi_instance = models.BooleanField() # This determines if the Category's Properties can be applied more than once on a Variant
    ...
```

..yet, this functionality probably gives more problems as it might break relations if the user later decides to set `multi_instance` from `True` to `False` etc.

Maybe I could extend the normal `PropertyCategory` with `MultiPropertyCategory`?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a common problem. Even though `properties` looks like it's part of a `Variant`, that `ManyToManyField` declaration is actually causing the creation of a whole new table that references both `Variants` and `Properties` by their primary keys. So when a `Variant` is created there are, strictly speaking, *no* `Properties` associated with it, since that can only happen once the `Variant` exists in the database. That's why trying to do the validation by overriding the `Model.save()` method - a common first approach - can't work.

Similarly, you can provide [custom validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) by overriding the `Model.clean()` method, but at the time this is called (via `ModelForm.is_valid()`, say) the object and its references haven't yet been added to the database.

If you're using Django's forms (including the admin site), look into [ModelForm validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform). Basically, you'll be overriding the `clean()` method of the ModelForm and validating the form rather than the `Model` itself.

As for your second question, your idea of adding a `BooleanField` sounds fine to me. If you're worried about users *inappropriately* changing that value then you can control their access to `PropertyCategories` using permissions in the admin site (or restrict changes with validation). You're right that changing the value from `True` to `False` would present a problem, but that's a conceptual issue and will be true regardless of the particular method you choose for implementation.

Comment: I would great appreciate if you would want to look at my new question based on this same principal but with refactored code (I switched Product and Variant around and added validate_unique). It seems the problem you describe is still there, probably this time in because of the Admin, because the M2M fields are already exist, this shouldn't be the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027371/validate-unique-to-calculate-what-is-to-come-instead-of-what-is